# How to recover deleted rows from SQL server table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, data-loss

I accidentaly ran a DELETE command against a table with a wrong WHERE
clause.

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Is there a way that could help me recover the lost data?

Comment: Unless you have a backup - which you can restore  - think you might be in trouble!!

Comment: Thank you. I needed that. I'm not alone. (Hope someone comes up with a way you can recover, though.)

Comment: I think there are definitely 3rd party tools around - http://apex-sql-log.apex-sql-llc.qarchive.org/ or Red Gate's SQL Log Rescue http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/ might work - but these are all commercial paid products

Comment: I made the same mistake... :(

Comment: The correct link for ApexSQL Log is http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx

Comment: You can find the complete step by step instruction how to recover deleted rows from SQL server table in this article https://sqlbak.com/blog/recover-deleted-data-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 10):

It is possible using Apex Recovery Tool,i have successfully recovered my table rows which i accidentally deleted

if you download the trial version it will recover only 10th row

check here http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx

Comment: I was able to recover my deleted rows, even on a database with simple recovery model.

Answer (score 8):

You have Full data + Transaction log backups, right?  You can restore to another Database from backups and then sync the deleted rows back. Lots of work though...

(Have you looked at [Redgate's SQL Log Rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/)? **Update**: it's SQL Server 2000 only)

There is [Log Explorer](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx?_kk=log%20explorer)

Answer (score 5):

I think thats impossible, sorry.

Thats why whenever running a delete or update you should always use `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, then `COMMIT` if successful or `ROLLBACK` if not.

Answer (score 3):

What is gone is gone.  The only protection I know of is regular backup.

Comment: That's perhaps not entirely accurate, but it is a useful general guideline to be taken into consideration *before* running a `DELETE` command.