# How to get back the deleted row?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have run delete wrong row from table how can i get back that row.
I am using sqlserver 2008

```
delete  from tblpayment where Payment_OrderID=11122
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't unless you have a backup.

Comment: Your question sounds similar to [How to recover deleted rows from SQL server table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540729/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-sql-server-table) Just have a look and I believe that it may help you , specially the [external link](http://raresql.com/2011/10/22/how-to-recover-deleted-data-from-sql-sever/) specified over there.

Comment: see also: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/995/how-do-i-get-back-some-deleted-records

Answer (score 0):

NO. You cannot do that easily in sql server unless its not done within a transaction.

Best option is to restore from backup