# How can we retrieve deleted rows in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Can we retrieve back deleted rows of table(s) from a database in SQL Server 2008 ?

If yes please let me know how can we do this?

Comment: see this: [How do I get back some deleted records?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/998)

Comment: You can get your answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/995/how-do-i-get-back-some-deleted-records)

Answer (score 2):

The example below is for 2005, maybe it need tweaks for 2008.

An easier way may be to restore it which is going to be based on your backups

[How to recover deleted rows from SQL server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540729/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-sql-server-table)

[Recover Deleted Rows From Sql Server Database](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/transactsql/thread/86befdbe-9806-4d96-9e9f-ead753d0fc20)

Comment: Thanks ankit, john & anand for quick response. I ll mark it close.