# How to roll back deleted data in SQL Server table for last deleted

Tags: sql-server

I would like to ask you a question I deleted data from table `HR_EMPMAST` and I want to roll back it the last delete. Could you help me please?

```
DELETE FROM HR_EMPMAST
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540729/how-to-recover-deleted-rows-from-sql-server-table If your recovery mode set to full, it is possible to recover https://sqlbak.com/blog/recover-deleted-data-in-sql-server/

Comment: If you're doing this inside an explicit **transaction** block (`BEGIN TRANSACTION .....`), then you could inspect the results and optionally issue a `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

Comment: I would like to say thank you for your answer. I have database backup but column table not match i just add column and restore table with data from my database backup

Comment: Sad life................ :'(

Answer (score 1):

The simple and sad answer is: you can not.

They only way to 'undo' such a `DELETE FROM` statement is if you actually have saved a back-up from your database from before the delete.  You can then either import that back-up in full or you can use the `IMPORT FROM` statement.

Unfortunately, if you have not saved a copy, that data is lost.  That is also why the sql admin asks you if you are sure you want to delete. in-revertible!

Comment: You told OP "you can't" and then outlined how you can... There's some faulty logic in there.

Comment: there is no way of actually 'rolling back' like the CTRL-Z, that command does not exist.  If you wrongfully deleted something, you can only hope for good backups.  I have edited the post slightly, to clear the logic :)